# Dagger/MissingBinding: android.app.Application cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method

Tags: android, dagger-2

Im using dagger in android. in my module I have a method which has a Application dependency.
the code below:

```
@Module
public class NetworkModule {

    @Provides
    public Drawable provideAppDrawable(Application application) {
        return ContextCompat.getDrawable(application, R.drawable.logo);
    }
}
```

but when I compile, I get the error above in title. an I missing something here?

AppComponent interface:

```
@Component(modules = {NetworkModule.class})
public interface AppComponent {

    void inject(AuthActivity authActivity);
}
```

Activity:

```
public class AuthActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "AuthActivity";

    @Inject
    Drawable logo;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        AppComponent appComponent  = DaggerAppComponent.create();
        appComponent.inject(this);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_auth);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well yes, you are not providing `Application` to the `AppComponent` anywhere. Although it is already a mystery to me why a Drawable is provided through Dagger.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce drawable is for example. How can I provide application? I was assuming inject method in activity did that for me.

Comment: `@BindsInstance`